# Default LESS function argument initially set as another argument?

Tags: css, arguments, less

Take this example function:

```
.linear-gradient(
    @begin: black,
    @end: white,
    @switch : 100%,
    @default: @begin
) {
    background:  @default;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(@begin), color-stop(@switch, @end));
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
    background: linear-gradient(top, @begin, @end @switch);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have a default value for the @default argument set initially as whatever is passed as the @begin argument UNLESS a fourth argument is passed from the function, in which case it takes that value.

Is this possible? This is my first day with LESS so perhaps I've missed some syntactic trick in the documentation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need to be using 1.4+ version of LESS

This [was an issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1281) that was resolved in the release of 1.4. My testing shows that it does in fact work in 1.4 (see the compiler at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/)), so you need to be sure you are using the latest version.

If you are using that version, then either your particular compiler has a bug, or something else in your code is wrong.

Comment: Nice one, this is the problem! I do actually have LESS version 1.4.0 but I'm using LiveReload and I wasn't aware that it refused to use the system version of LESS and instead uses a bundled version which after a little digging around, turns out to be 1.3.3.

Time to change my workflow until LiveReload gets an update :(